# insert data from windows app to web service

Tags: c#

I want to pass and add data to the web service through a desktop program by stored procedure in SQL Server.

Stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insert_user]
    (@code nvarchar(50), 
     @codeuser nvarchar(50), 
     @pictureuser image,
     @nameshop nvarchar(50),
     @country nvarchar(50),
     @addressuser nvarchar(50),
     @telephone nvarchar(20),
     @passworact nvarchar(20),
     @dateregist date,
     @active bit)
AS
    INSERT INTO   user_tb (code, codeuser, pictureuser, nameshop, 
                           country, addressuser, telephone, passworact, dateregist, active) 
    VALUES (@code, @codeuser, @pictureuser, @nameshop,
            @country, @addressuser, @telephone, @passworact, @dateregist, @active)
```

Web service add

```
[WebMethod]
public int Insertregester(string code, string codeuser, byte pictureuser, string nameshop, string country, string addressuser, string telephone, string passworact, DateTime dateregist, Boolean active)
{
        int retRecord = 0;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert_user", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@code", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = code;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@codeuser", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = codeuser;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@pictureuser", SqlDbType.Image).Value = pictureuser;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@nameshop", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = nameshop;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@country", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = country;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@addressuser", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = addressuser;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@telephone", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = telephone;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@passworact", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = passworact;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@dateregist", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dateregist.ToShortDateString();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@active", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = active;
               
                if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    con.Open();
                }

                retRecord = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        return retRecord 
}
```

Call service  code in windows app

```
Servicea.WebServiceSoapClient _service = new WindowsForm_webservice.Servicea.WebServiceSoapClient();
```

This is the first time I have used the service.

My attempt:

```
ms = new MemoryStream();
pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

byte[] photo_aray = new byte[ms.Length];
ms.Position = 0;
ms.Read(photo_aray, 0, photo_aray.Length);

_service.Insertregester(("22"), ("4578"), (photo_aray), (TEXT_NAME.Text), (TEXT_ADDRESS.Text), (TEXT_ADDRESS.Text), (TEXT_TEL.Text), (TEXT_PASSWO.Text),(DATE_PICK.Value.ToShortDateString),(true));
```

I get this error:

[image]

Comment: 1) the third parameter of `Insertregester` should be a `byte[]` 2) `dateregist` is a date, but you're passing it a **method** - `DATE_PICK.Value.ToShortDateString`

Comment: `image` data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data type in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: thanks stuartd    thanks  marc_s